# How can I fix the the highlighter's offset in Microsoft OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote

Okay, so for some reason, whenever I use the highlighter on Microsoft OneNote, the highlighted ink ALWAYS shows up a certain horizontal offset away from my cursor. And it's annoying. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I also have the same problem.